# Python arguments for maximum

Tags: python, arguments, max, equation

i have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def rownanie(Y, t, l, q, a, u):
    y1, y2, z1, z2 = Y
    dydt = [y2, ((l*q)/a)*(1/y1)*(1-z2*u), z2, (a*y2*u)/y1]
    return dydt

l = 100
q = 1
a = 10
u = 0.25

y0 = -1
z0 = 0
y0_prim, z0_prim = 0, 0  
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 10001)
sol = odeint(rownanie, [y0, y0_prim, z0, z0_prim], t, args=(l,q,a,u))
print(sol)


plt.plot(sol[:, 0], sol[:, 2]) 
plt.xlabel('Y')
plt.ylabel('Z')
plt.grid()
```

So i have 4 columns of data, lets say [:, 0] till [:,0]. I have to focus only on two : [:, 0] , [:, 2]. When i make a graph of it - its a harmonic function. [:, 0] are values , [:, 2] are arguments. I need to find these arguments for which values are max. Or i need the difference, the distance beetween two arguments (two maxes) I tried with "if", but the values are approximations so they are not the same. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: I'll refer you to the Python built-in functions https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html
You'll find a function there called max(), and also abs() for you to find the absolute difference between two maximums. Hope that helps

Comment: So max() gives me one maximum, but due to the precision there are other, let's say, the values are little lower.

Comment: You want to find the maximum of `[:, 0]`?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what exactly you want. Elaborate more

Comment: Just posted picture below to clarify.

Comment: @PatrykLange: Got it. Check my reply

Comment: I see what you're doing now. Bazingaa's answer looks correct; if you think so, please mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, you need to define a tolerance for the difference with respect to the maximum value. I marked the points for clarification. The idea here is to first get the difference from the maximum of values `max(sol[:, 0])`. Then you can use the NumPy array's indexing using a tolerance of 1e-4. `[abs(diff) < 1e-4]` returns your indices where this condition holds True. Now you have these maximum 5 points. You can do whatever processing you want with them. The choice of tolerance will depend also on your number of mesh points (10001 in this case). It requires some playing around. One can also write some function to check this smartly.

```
diff = sol[:, 0] - max(sol[:, 0])
plt.plot(sol[:, 0], sol[:, 2]) 
plt.plot(sol[:, 0][abs(diff) < 1e-4], sol[:, 2][abs(diff) < 1e-4], 'kx')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA41a.png)

And i need to find this difference but every maximum is a little bit different